# RewriteRule re-naming url with parameter do not work

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want this url: 
 http://www.website.com/article?a=article-id

become this url: 
http://www.website.com/article-id

I have tried this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\$ /article?a=$1 [L]
```

I also tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z-/]+)$ article?a=$1 [QSA]
```

none is working.

Thx

This is the code I have at .htaccess

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php .php5 .php4 .php3  

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bepo\.co.il$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [L,R=301]

errorDocument 404 http://www.website.com

Options -Indexes


RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: You have this `I want this url` backwards (but I am dyslexic so maybe I am backwards) - You should put the "pretty" URL in the browser and turn it into the ugly url on the server.  In any case you cannot change the URL in the browser without a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/article$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^a=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1? [L,QSA]
```